# Rocksdb change compaction style, the exsisted data will be correct?

Tags: database, rocksdb

If I open Rocksdb with leveled compaction style and insert some data. And then, I reopen Rocksdb with universal compaction style. The rocksdb can work correct or not?

https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Leveled-Compaction
https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Universal-Compaction

According to the docs, I think the structures are similar, but I can't find a answer about it.